# Magento 2 Advanced Reporting Exception Log and its link 404 Page

Tags: magento2, 404, advanced-reporting

I have  already enabled Advanced Reporting and integrated Active user in admin as Magento Analytics User under Admin => System => Integration

## Still it throws  below exception log:
Can anyone please let me know about this error. Server team also confirmed all permissions are set. Eventhough created folders "/tmp/analytics/tmp" manually with full permission(755) under root/ and pub/ directory.

[2021-04-25 00:00:04] main.CRITICAL: Directory "/tmp/analytics/tmp" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Directory "/tmp/analytics/tmp" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:225)"} []

=====================================================================
Please check below attached admin configuration screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From error permission issue.

You should set as bellow recommended Permissions.

cd `<your Magento install dir>`

**For files 644** : `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

**For Directory 755** : `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

**For var folder 777** : `find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

**For pub/media folder 777** : `find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

**For pub/static folder 777** : `find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

**For app/etc folder 777** : `chmod 777 ./app/etc`

**For app/etc .xml file 644** : `chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml`

chown -R : `<web server group> .`

`chmod u+x bin/magento`